# How to install Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, gruntjs, npm

I used [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install Node.js, then used `npm install` to install Grunt and its dependencies, but after the installation completed, I was not able to run Grunt:

```
zsh: correct 'grunt' to 'grn' ÆnyaeÅ? n
zsh: command not found: grunt
```

What is the proper method of installing Grunt so I do not get this error?

Answer (score 21):

To use Grunt on the command line, you have to install the command-line interface:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

The `-g` flag is for installing the module globally, which will also create a PATH variable for Grunt.

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install -g grunt-cli   => This will put the grunt command in your system path
```